# Xdebug is not working in Zend Studio 10

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug, zend-studio

I'm using Xdebug in Zend studio 10, and I use the zend framework 1.12.

I config the Xdebug and Zend studio as most tution.

At first, everything is OK, when I debug the project, the cursor stopped at the breakpoint.

But, I don't know what happened. Suddenly, the Xdebug seemed not woking. It never stopped at any breakpoint.(I restart the apache and zend studio for many times).

I have two PCs, and each of them has the same environment, and both of them meet this problem. So I think this is not a simple occasional problem.

Who know what happend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm so foolish.

I find the reason. There's button on the toolbar--`skip all breakpoints`
[image]

Just click the button. I wasted lots of time on this stupid problem.